# Complementary indices

Tags: python

I'm using `np.where` to find the indices of an array which satisfy a set of conditions. Is there an easy way to find the indices of all other elements which do not satisfy that condition? For e.g., if I use `ok=np.where((condition1) & (condition2))` on array `x` I can only find `x[ok]`. How do I find instead all elements in `x` that don't satisfy `ok`?

Answer (score 1):

If you store the condition itself separately, you can just negate it:

```
true_indices = (condition1) & (condition2)
false_indices = ~true_indices
```

You can then call `np.where` on these values if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, Lily.

In python, the boolean negation operator is `~`. It will give you the complement.

```
x = np.array([0, 1])
ok = np.where(x > 1)
not_ok = np.where(~(x > 1))
# you can also use this, if you already have ok
# where returns a tuple, the first index of which is the indices
not_ok = x[~ok[0]]
```